# Excel Mac - UserForm

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am so close to being able to fully use the UserForm on Mac Excel.

In the VB Editor I needed to go to Tools->References and Enable: Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3

Now if I add the following code in a sub and run the sub:

```
set objForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_MSForm)
```

It actually works!  A form control gets added in the project browser, I see the form and have the toolbox available and all properties.  But its one and done, I can't figure out how to go back and edit the form once I close that window.  I can edit the code but never get the designer window to pop up again.

I feel like its a hack but there's likely a different line of code that I can put in its own sub to trick VB Editor to open that designer window back up again.

Any ideas?

Comment: IME your best bet is to develop your forms on Windows, and only make minor tweaks and adjustments on a Mac. Depending on the version it's possible your IDE doesn't _have_ a designer for such forms, which leaves you with only 100% dynamic forms & controls if you can't develop them on a Windows machine. Good luck!